# How to find a dynamic element or attribute in XML using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

[image]

From the above image(XML), i want to get NL15 as value or what will be XPATH of NL15 ? NL15 is dynamic text it can be anything like AK15, SI22 ?

```json
    {
    "impact_matrix": {
        "id": 290,
        "id_of_source": 289,
        "impact_matrix_number": 271,
        "status": null,
        "revision": "AC",
        "reviser": {
            "user_id": "saingale",
            "full_name": "Sagar Ingale",
            "email": "sagar.ingale@asml.qas",
            "department_name": "IT Solution Delivery PLM/CM Conf&Change",
            "abbreviation": "SINJ"
        },
        "revision_description": "PARTS ADDED",
        "date_revised": "2022-10-04T21:51:23.167+00:00",
        "title": "impact matrix bys sagar",
        "contexts": [
            {
                "type": "CHANGENOTICE",
                "name": "I am some CN By SAGAR",
                "context_id": "410079",
                "status": "2"
            }
        ],
        "is_auto_layout_enabled": null
    },
    "parts": [
        {
            "id": 1854,
            "id_of_source": 1852,
            "status": null,
            "impact_matrix_id": 290,
            "source": null,
            "intention": {
                "product_id": "4022.123.1111",
                "revision": null,
                "name": null,
                "description": "ITEM 1",
                "vqi": "12121",
                "procurement_type": "E",
                "material_type": null,
                "serial_number_profile": "Z004",
                "critical_configuration_item_indicator": false,
                "regular_part_indicator": "true",
                "history_indicator": null,
                "predecessor_cross_plant_status": null,
                "cross_plant_status": "R1",
                "cross_plant_status_to_be": null,
                "tool_pack_category": "C",
                "tc_change_control": true,
                "sap_change_control": false,
                "allow_bom_restructuring": true,
                "unit_of_measure": null,
                "item_usage": null,
                "is_phantom": null,
                "failure_rate": "111",
                "in_house_production_time": null,
                "sl_abc_code": [
                    "U",
                    "W",
                    "J"
                ],
                "production_plant": null,
                "limited_driving12_nc": null,
                "limited_driving12_ncflag": null,
                "multi_plant": "TESTING MULTI PLANT",
                "part_bom_intention_type": "UNI",
                "plant_specific": {
                    "NL15": {
                        "object_dependency": "aa",
                        "ref_material": "WW",
                        "is_discontinued": true
                    }
                },
                "id": "52996cf0-ed0b-4e8e-9234-1d6c43c6058a",
                "assigned_release_packages": [
                    {
                        "id": "410079-01",
                        "title": "New CR",
                        "release_package_number": "410079-01",
                        "release_package_title": "New CR",
                        "status": "1",
                        "ecn": null
                    }
                ],
                "change_indication": "NEW",
                "type": "D_M"
            },
            "layouts": {
                "DBOM": {
                    "x": -515.0,
                    "y": -159.5,
                    "height": 170.0,
                    "width": 278.0
                }
            },
            "views": [
                "DBOM",
                "MBOM"
            ],
            "item_references": null,
            "change_indication": null,
            "is_parent_part_bom_changed": null,
            "hidden_bom_parents": null,
            "hidden_bom_children": null
        },
        {
            "id": 1855,
            "id_of_source": 1853,
            "status": null,
            "impact_matrix_id": 290,
            "source": null,
            "intention": {
                "product_id": "4022.123.11112",
                "revision": null,
                "name": null,
                "description": "ITEM 2",
                "vqi": "RREE",
                "procurement_type": "E",
                "material_type": "ASSY",
                "serial_number_profile": "ZN02",
                "critical_configuration_item_indicator": true,
                "regular_part_indicator": "true",
                "history_indicator": null,
                "predecessor_cross_plant_status": null,
                "cross_plant_status": "R2",
                "cross_plant_status_to_be": null,
                "tool_pack_category": "E",
                "tc_change_control": false,
                "sap_change_control": true,
                "allow_bom_restructuring": true,
                "unit_of_measure": null,
                "item_usage": "DBOM",
                "is_phantom": null,
                "failure_rate": "21",
                "in_house_production_time": null,
                "sl_abc_code": [
                    "6",
                    "9"
                ],
                "production_plant": null,
                "limited_driving12_nc": null,
                "limited_driving12_ncflag": null,
                "multi_plant": "TEST DATA",
                "part_bom_intention_type": "UNI",
                "plant_specific": {
                    "US21": {
                        "object_dependency": "EEWWW",
                        "ref_material": "",
                        "is_discontinued": true
                    },
                    "US22": {
                        "object_dependency": "RR",
                        "ref_material": "",
                        "is_discontinued": false
                    }
                },
                "id": "bfa9d58b-de19-4af5-83e3-b2a5f77097dd",
                "assigned_release_packages": [
                    {
                        "id": "410079-01",
                        "title": "New CR",
                        "release_package_number": "410079-01",
                        "release_package_title": "New CR",
                        "status": "1",
                        "ecn": null
                    }
                ],
                "change_indication": "NEW",
                "type": "D_ONLY"
            },
            "layouts": {
                "DBOM": {
                    "x": -454.0,
                    "y": -58.5,
                    "height": 170.0,
                    "width": 278.0
                }
            },
            "views": [
                "DBOM"
            ],
            "item_references": null,
            "change_indication": null,
            "is_parent_part_bom_changed": null,
            "hidden_bom_parents": null,
            "hidden_bom_children": null
        }
    ],
    "boms": null,
    "notes": null,
    "frames": null
}
```

Here is json from which i generated xml.

Here is XML

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ActivityOutputClass xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/json">
    <ns1:ImpactMatrixAggregate xmlns:ns1="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/bin_bpm_sap_material/Resources/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
        <ns1:impact_matrix>
            <ns1:id>290</ns1:id>
            <ns1:id_of_source>289</ns1:id_of_source>
            <ns1:impact_matrix_number>271</ns1:impact_matrix_number>
            <ns1:status/>
            <ns1:revision>AC</ns1:revision>
            <ns1:reviser>
                <ns1:user_id>saingale</ns1:user_id>
                <ns1:full_name>Sagar Ingale</ns1:full_name>
                <ns1:email>sagar.ingale@asml.qas</ns1:email>
                <ns1:department_name>IT Solution Delivery PLM/CM Conf&amp;Change</ns1:department_name>
                <ns1:abbreviation>SINJ</ns1:abbreviation>
            </ns1:reviser>
            <ns1:revision_description>PARTS ADDED</ns1:revision_description>
            <ns1:date_revised>2022-10-04T21:51:23.167Z</ns1:date_revised>
            <ns1:title>impact matrix bys sagar</ns1:title>
            <ns1:contexts>
                <ns1:type>CHANGENOTICE</ns1:type>
                <ns1:name>I am some CN By SAGAR</ns1:name>
                <ns1:context_id>410079</ns1:context_id>
                <ns1:status>2</ns1:status>
            </ns1:contexts>
            <ns1:is_auto_layout_enabled/>
        </ns1:impact_matrix>
        <ns1:parts>
            <ns1:id>1854</ns1:id>
            <ns1:id_of_source>1852</ns1:id_of_source>
            <ns1:status/>
            <ns1:source/>
            <ns1:intention>
                <ns1:product_id>4022.123.1111</ns1:product_id>
                <ns1:revision/>
                <ns1:name/>
                <ns1:description>ITEM 1</ns1:description>
                <ns1:vqi>12121</ns1:vqi>
                <ns1:procurement_type>E</ns1:procurement_type>
                <ns1:material_type/>
                <ns1:serial_number_profile>Z004</ns1:serial_number_profile>
                <ns1:critical_configuration_item_indicator>false</ns1:critical_configuration_item_indicator>
                <ns1:regular_part_indicator>true</ns1:regular_part_indicator>
                <ns1:history_indicator/>
                <ns1:predecessor_cross_plant_status/>
                <ns1:cross_plant_status>R1</ns1:cross_plant_status>
                <ns1:cross_plant_status_to_be/>
                <ns1:tool_pack_category>C</ns1:tool_pack_category>
                <ns1:tc_change_control>true</ns1:tc_change_control>
                <ns1:sap_change_control>false</ns1:sap_change_control>
                <ns1:allow_bom_restructuring>true</ns1:allow_bom_restructuring>
                <ns1:unit_of_measure/>
                <ns1:item_usage/>
                <ns1:is_phantom/>
                <ns1:failure_rate>111</ns1:failure_rate>
                <ns1:in_house_production_time/>
                <ns1:sl_abc_code>U</ns1:sl_abc_code>
                <ns1:sl_abc_code>W</ns1:sl_abc_code>
                <ns1:sl_abc_code>J</ns1:sl_abc_code>
                <ns1:production_plant/>
                <ns1:limited_driving12_nc/>
                <ns1:limited_driving12_ncflag/>
                <ns1:multi_plant>TESTING MULTI PLANT</ns1:multi_plant>
                <ns1:part_bom_intention_type>UNI</ns1:part_bom_intention_type>
                <ns1:plant_specific>
                    <NL15>
                        <object_dependency>aa</object_dependency>
                        <ref_material>WW</ref_material>
                        <is_discontinued>true</is_discontinued>
                    </NL15>
                </ns1:plant_specific>
                <ns1:id>52996cf0-ed0b-4e8e-9234-1d6c43c6058a</ns1:id>
                <ns1:assigned_release_packages>
                    <ns1:id>410079-01</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:title>New CR</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:release_package_number>410079-01</ns1:release_package_number>
                    <ns1:release_package_title>New CR</ns1:release_package_title>
                    <ns1:status>1</ns1:status>
                    <ns1:ecn/>
                </ns1:assigned_release_packages>
                <ns1:change_indication>NEW</ns1:change_indication>
                <ns1:type>D_M</ns1:type>
            </ns1:intention>
            <ns1:layouts>
                <ns1:DBOM>
                    <ns1:x>-515.0</ns1:x>
                    <ns1:y>-159.5</ns1:y>
                    <ns1:height>170.0</ns1:height>
                    <ns1:width>278.0</ns1:width>
                </ns1:DBOM>
            </ns1:layouts>
            <ns1:views>DBOM</ns1:views>
            <ns1:views>MBOM</ns1:views>
            <ns1:item_references/>
            <ns1:change_indication/>
            <ns1:is_parent_part_bom_changed/>
            <ns1:hidden_bom_parents/>
            <ns1:hidden_bom_children/>
            <impact_matrix_id>290</impact_matrix_id>
        </ns1:parts>
        <ns1:parts>
            <ns1:id>1855</ns1:id>
            <ns1:id_of_source>1853</ns1:id_of_source>
            <ns1:status/>
            <ns1:source/>
            <ns1:intention>
                <ns1:product_id>4022.123.11112</ns1:product_id>
                <ns1:revision/>
                <ns1:name/>
                <ns1:description>ITEM 2</ns1:description>
                <ns1:vqi>RREE</ns1:vqi>
                <ns1:procurement_type>E</ns1:procurement_type>
                <ns1:material_type>ASSY</ns1:material_type>
                <ns1:serial_number_profile>ZN02</ns1:serial_number_profile>
                <ns1:critical_configuration_item_indicator>true</ns1:critical_configuration_item_indicator>
                <ns1:regular_part_indicator>true</ns1:regular_part_indicator>
                <ns1:history_indicator/>
                <ns1:predecessor_cross_plant_status/>
                <ns1:cross_plant_status>R2</ns1:cross_plant_status>
                <ns1:cross_plant_status_to_be/>
                <ns1:tool_pack_category>E</ns1:tool_pack_category>
                <ns1:tc_change_control>false</ns1:tc_change_control>
                <ns1:sap_change_control>true</ns1:sap_change_control>
                <ns1:allow_bom_restructuring>true</ns1:allow_bom_restructuring>
                <ns1:unit_of_measure/>
                <ns1:item_usage>DBOM</ns1:item_usage>
                <ns1:is_phantom/>
                <ns1:failure_rate>21</ns1:failure_rate>
                <ns1:in_house_production_time/>
                <ns1:sl_abc_code>6</ns1:sl_abc_code>
                <ns1:sl_abc_code>9</ns1:sl_abc_code>
                <ns1:production_plant/>
                <ns1:limited_driving12_nc/>
                <ns1:limited_driving12_ncflag/>
                <ns1:multi_plant>TEST DATA</ns1:multi_plant>
                <ns1:part_bom_intention_type>UNI</ns1:part_bom_intention_type>
                <ns1:plant_specific>
                    <US21>
                        <object_dependency>EEWWW</object_dependency>
                        <ref_material/>
                        <is_discontinued>true</is_discontinued>
                    </US21>
                    <US22>
                        <object_dependency>RR</object_dependency>
                        <ref_material/>
                        <is_discontinued>false</is_discontinued>
                    </US22>
                </ns1:plant_specific>
                <ns1:id>bfa9d58b-de19-4af5-83e3-b2a5f77097dd</ns1:id>
                <ns1:assigned_release_packages>
                    <ns1:id>410079-01</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:title>New CR</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:release_package_number>410079-01</ns1:release_package_number>
                    <ns1:release_package_title>New CR</ns1:release_package_title>
                    <ns1:status>1</ns1:status>
                    <ns1:ecn/>
                </ns1:assigned_release_packages>
                <ns1:change_indication>NEW</ns1:change_indication>
                <ns1:type>D_ONLY</ns1:type>
            </ns1:intention>
            <ns1:layouts>
                <ns1:DBOM>
                    <ns1:x>-454.0</ns1:x>
                    <ns1:y>-58.5</ns1:y>
                    <ns1:height>170.0</ns1:height>
                    <ns1:width>278.0</ns1:width>
                </ns1:DBOM>
            </ns1:layouts>
            <ns1:views>DBOM</ns1:views>
            <ns1:item_references/>
            <ns1:change_indication/>
            <ns1:is_parent_part_bom_changed/>
            <ns1:hidden_bom_parents/>
            <ns1:hidden_bom_children/>
            <impact_matrix_id>290</impact_matrix_id>
        </ns1:parts>
        <ns1:boms/>
        <ns1:notes/>
        <ns1:frames/>
    </ns1:ImpactMatrixAggregate>
</ns0:ActivityOutputClass>
```

Under Plant Specific , there can be different objects with same attributes , which you will see in the xml / json ?

My input will be productId= 4022.xxx.xxx and PlantName=US21, so now i need to give information related to that productId for Plant US21 , but there can be different plants info avaialble for same product id.

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 3.1. All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please specify your logic for finding the element you've highlighted. Will it always be the only child element of an `ns:plant_specific` element? Please also include the XML in a code block, rather than as an image. Make sure you include a full XML document; cut out irrelevant portions if you need to save space, but it should be well-formed XML with the namespace declarations intact.

Comment: Added Required inputs.

Comment: First, you say "Here is json from which i generated xml." - if you generated the xml from a json, why did you bother - can't you extract the data you need directly from the json? Second, the xml you generated is not well formed; run it through an xml validator to see why. Third - you haven't responded to @ConalTuohy's important request:  "specify your logic for finding the element you've highlighted".

Comment: for that logic only i am asking question , how to get that highlighted element. I have tried like following ways - 
$Parse-JSON/ns13:ActivityOutputClass/pfx14:ImpactMatrixAggregate/pfx14:parts[pfx14:id= $var]/pfx14:intention/pfx14:plant_specific